# How to create list button with in SF lightning interface?

Tags: lightning, multi-select, standardsetcontroller, list-button

I have list button on Contact search layout with vf page and set controller. It is ok for SF classic but in Lightning interface do not have check boxes for multiselect for the contacts even though checked "Display Checkboxes (for Multi-Record Selection)" option on the button. [image]

It is possible to pass all the items using stSetController into custom page which replicates search layout + checkboxes (custom multiselect). Does somebody knows other options for multiselect in Lightning?